# add the third party font method in android

Tags: android, fonts

I add the third party font in android. And I put the font in the root of assets/fonts/qqqq.ttf

```
type=Typeface.createFromFile("@assets/fonts/hwxk.ttf"); 
 tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.index_grid_detail_text);
 tv.setTypeface(type);
```

But it has the error like: native  typeface cannot be made.

What is the problem? anyone knows this? thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code instead of your code after `setContentView();`, may be it will solve your problem.

```
// text view label
TextView mTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DroidSansFallback.ttf");

// Applying font
mTextView1.setTypeface(tf);
```

And see below link for more information.

[Customize Android Fonts](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-development-customize-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as if font is placed within assets dir in Project:

```
Typeface type= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/hwxk.ttf");
tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.index_grid_detail_text);
tv.setTypeface(type);
```

and for Creating Custom font from Sdcard change your code as:

```
Typeface type= Typeface.createFromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/assets/fonts/hwxk.ttf"));
tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.index_grid_detail_text);
tv.setTypeface(type);
```

Add sdcard permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```